# Custom query assistance needed

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have 3 tables: (simplified for this question)

- `REQUIREMENTS` : ID (PK), RequirementDescription
- `CUSTOMERS` : ID (PK), CustomerName
- `CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS` (join table): ID (PK), RequirementID (FK to REQUIREMENTS table), CustomerID (FK to CUSTOMERS table), DateCompleted

Question: I need to make a gridview in asp.net that basically shows the requirements on the left, all the customers as column headings and the `DateCompleted` as the "intersection". How can I do this?

For example:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show us your **current effort** and explain where you're stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following sql and replace temp tables with your table:

CREATE TABLE #REQUIREMENTS
(
    ID INT,
    RequirementDescription VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE #CUSTOMERS
(
    ID INT,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS
(
    ID INT, 
    RequirementID INT, 
    CustomerID INT, 
    DateCompleted DATE
)

INSERT INTO #REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,'Requirement1')

INSERT INTO #REQUIREMENTS VALUES (2,'Requirement2')

INSERT INTO #REQUIREMENTS VALUES (3,'Requirement3')

INSERT INTO #REQUIREMENTS VALUES (4,'Requirement4')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMERS VALUES (1,'JOHN')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMERS VALUES (2,'MARY')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMERS VALUES (3,'BOB')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,1,1,'2-2-2014')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,2,1,'2-2-2014')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,1,2,'2-2-2014')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,2,2,'2-2-2014')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,3,2,'2-2-2014')

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS VALUES (1,4,2,'2-2-2014')

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(CustomerName) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName FROM #CUSTOMERS) AS Courses

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ReqID, ReqDes, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT
            TEMP.ReqID,
            TEMP.ReqDes,
            TEMP.CusName,
            CusReq.DateCompleted
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                req.ID as ReqID,
                req.RequirementDescription as ReqDes,
                cus.ID as CusID,
                cus.CustomerName as CusName 
            FROM 
                #REQUIREMENTS req,#CUSTOMERS cus
        ) AS TEMP
        LEFT JOIN
            #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS as CusReq
        ON
            TEMP.ReqID = CusReq.RequirementID AND
            Temp.CusID = CusReq.CustomerID
    ) AS TEMP1
    PIVOT(MAX(TEMP1.DateCompleted)
          FOR CusName IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery

DROP TABLE #CUSTOMER_REQUIREMENTS

DROP TABLE #CUSTOMERS

DROP TABLE #REQUIREMENTS

Comment: Thanks! Great example! Can the main processing (after creating/populating the temp tables) be converted into a 1 line SELECT statement with no variables?

Comment: @WebDevGuy if the column which are pivoting has static/fixed data then you can replace dynamic query with select statement. But when column data is dynamic like customer whether new customer are added and you have to show all of them then you have to generate dynamic sql.